# Why am I receiving C2440 error for string when trying to open file using <netcdf> library?

Tags: c++, netcdf

I am trying to read a netCDF file with the  library in C++. However, I am getting a C2440 error, telling me that I cannot convert the type of the dataFile to the dataVar. Or, at least this is what I think it is telling me because the compiler error seems a little cryptic to read.

Here is my code:

```
//create a test object to open netcdf file 
    const std::vector<std::string> path = obj.getPaths(); //returns all paths in the netcdf directory
    const std::string test = path[0]; //gives me a test path that is element 1 in the path vector

    netCDF::NcFile dataFile(test, netCDF::NcFile::read);
    netCDF::NcVar dataVar = dataFile.getVars();
```

error:

```
Error C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::multimap<std::string,netCDF::NcVar,std::less<Aws::String>,std::allocator<std::pair<conststd::string,netCDF::NcVar>>>' to 'netCDF::NcVar' count-lightning C:\Users\Corey4005\Desktop\Dev\projects\count-lightning\src\main.cpp 59
```

What should I do to make this code work?

Thanks for the help!

What I have tried:

I tried to open a netcdf file using the NcFile stream. The NcFile stream takes the following arguments:

```
netCDF::NcFile dataFile(const std::string &filePath, netCDF::NcFile::fileMode fMode);
```

When I provided a string literal to the filePath argument, I received a C2440 'initializing' error. I am confused because I think I am correctly passing a const string literal to a const string argument.

Comment: Use `auto dataVar = ... ` if it's difficult to consult with [`netCDF::NcFile::getVars`](https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf-cxx/current/classnetCDF_1_1NcGroup.html#a940af4077eeccbbb232b844253f7395c) manual.

Comment: As the error message says, `dataFile.getVars()` returns a multimap, and an attempt is made to assign it to something else. This has nothing to do, whatsoever, with what `dataFile` is, but with what `dataFile.getVars()` returns.

Comment: The error is reported for `netCDF::NcVar dataVar = dataFile.getVars();` not the `NcFile` object instantiation (presumably line 59?)

Comment: My bad. You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

`netCDF::NcVar dataVar` is a single variable, `dataFile.getVars()` returns multiple variables in a map. The simplest fix is to use:

```
auto dataVar = dataFile.getVars();
```

Or:

```
std::multimap< std::string, NcVar > dataVar = dataFile.getVars();
```

If you actually wanted to get a single variable you need to provide a name:

```
netCDF::NcVar dataVar = dataFile.getVar("myvar");
```

See http://unidata.github.io/netcdf-cxx4/classnetCDF_1_1NcFile.html